# How to change the archive title to use the plural version of the taxonomy label instead of the singular

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, taxonomy

I have a simple Wordpress blog with two categories: slugs are 'comment' and 'press_release'. When I am on a single.php page of posts of either category, it should display 'Comment' or 'Press Release'. When I am on archive.php of either category's archive, I want to title it either 'Comments' or 'Press Releases'.

I've added this code to functions.php, but it just makes the whole site blank in the browser.

--- UPDATED CODE ---

from `functions.php`:

```
$labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Kommentare', 'taxonomy general name'),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Kommentar', 'taxonomy singular name'),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Kommentare')
);

$labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Pressemitteilungen', 'taxonomy general name'),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Pressemitteilung', 'taxonomy singular name'),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Pressemitteilungen')
);

add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', function ( $title ) {

    if( is_tax() ) {
        $tax = get_taxonomy( get_queried_object()->taxonomy );
        /* use the "name" label instead of "singular_name" to showl the plural version */
        $title = sprintf( __( '%1$s: %2$s' ), 
                 $tax->labels->name, 
                 single_term_title( '', false ) );
    }
    return $title;
});
```

on indexes (for plural version) like `archive.php`:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

   <?php $post = $posts[0]; ?>

      <?php if (is_category()) { ?>

         <h2><?php echo get_the_archive_title(); ?></h2>

      <?php } elseif (is_author()) { ?>

         <h2><?php _e('Veröffentlicht von %s'); ?></h2>

   <?php } ?>
```

(but echoes 'Kategorie: Pressemitteilung' instead of 'Pressemitteilungen'.)

on single post pages such as `single.php` within the usual code block:

```
<?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { echo $category->cat_name; } ?>
```

--- END UPDATED CODE ---

--- NEWLY UPDATED CODE ---

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_taxonomies', 0 );
function create_taxonomies() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'          => _x( 'Pressemitteilungen', 'taxonomy general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Pressemitteilung', 'taxonomy singular name'),
        'menu_name'     => __( 'Pressemitteilungen')
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'pressemitteilung' )
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'pressemitteilung', array( 'post' ), $args );

        $labels = array(
            'name'              => _x( 'Kommentare', 'taxonomy general name'),
            'singular_name'     => _x( 'Kommentar', 'taxonomy singular name'),
            'menu_name'         => __( 'Kommentare')
        );

        $args = array(
            'hierarchical'      => true,
            'labels'            => $labels,
            'query_var'         => true,
            'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'kommentar' )
        );

        register_taxonomy( 'kommentar', array( 'post' ), $args );
}

add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', function ( $title ) {
    if( is_tax() ) {
        $tax = get_taxonomy( get_queried_object()->taxonomy );
        $title = sprintf( __( '%2$s' ),
                 $tax->labels->name,
                 single_term_title( '', false ) );
    }
    return $title;
});
```

--- END NEWLY UPDATED CODE ---

Note, that I can't "soft-fix" it with adding the letter 's' right after '%s'. I can't use that because I want to use that on a German weblog and there the plural forms are not all consistent (like with an extra 's).

Is it a syntax error or am I doing it completely wrong?

Comment: Is that your complete function?  You're missing a `}` at the end for a start. Where is this getting called - in other  words, what action are you using in `add_action`? Also, did my answer to your previous question help or did you need more help? You never responded either way...

Comment: Yeah, sorry I wasn't able to get back on it yet or try it. I will! Thanks!

Comment: No problem, let me know if it works or now. Anyway, this question... is the missing `}` a typo in your question or is it missing from your PHP? A syntax error can cause a blank screen. If it was a typo, what action are you using?

Comment: I have updated the code here with both things you mentioned :-) /edit: it shows the pages again, but no change..

Comment: When you say "no change"  do you mean with the singular/plural?

Comment: When I load an archive page I want it to display the plural term. When I have a single post open, the singular term. Right now there is no effect with wor without the code.

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Comment: I am genuinely surprised that this all seems very hard to accomplish while I feel like this should be absolutely standard procedure and a built in functionality, like that you create a category in the backend and there is not only a field for title and slug but also for the plural term. The standard display "Archive for the 'blabla' category" seems like a very unnatural way of tilting something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WP uses the single label for taxonomy archives by default.

archive.php uses `get_the_archive_title` to show the title, which uses the singular_name as we can see from this line of code from `get_the_archive_title` that generates the title for taxonomy archives:

```
 $title = sprintf( __( '%1$s: %2$s' ), 
         $tax->labels->singular_name, 
         single_term_title( '', false ) );
```

Luckily, we can filter this using the `get_the_archive_title` filter. In our filter function, we we need to 
1. Check if the archive is for a taxonomy
2. if so, get the taxonomy from the queries object
3. generate the title in the same way as the `get_the_archive_title` function, but use 'name' instead of 'singular_name'.

**Add this to your functions.php to change the taxonomy archive title:**

```
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', function ( $title ) {

    if( is_tax() ) {
        $tax = get_taxonomy( get_queried_object()->taxonomy );
        /* use the "name" label instead of "singular_name" to showl the plural version */
        $title = sprintf( __( '%1$s: %2$s' ), 
                 $tax->labels->name, 
                 single_term_title( '', false ) );
    }
    return $title;
});
```

**Example:**

In your question, you defined the labels as follows:

```
$labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Comments', 'taxonomy general name'),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Comment', 'taxonomy singular name'),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Comments')
);
```

By default, WP will use the `singular_name` in archives, i.e. "Comment". The code above change it to use `name` instead, i.e. "Comments".

Changing this to use your German labels:

```
$labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Kommentare', 'taxonomy general name'),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Kommentar', 'taxonomy singular name'),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Kommentare')
);
```

The code above will now use 'Kommentare' thats set as the `name`, instead of "Kommentar" from `singular_name`.

UPDATE:

Below is the complete code I added to a test site and it works:

functions.php:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_taxonomies', 0 );
function create_taxonomies() { 
    $labels = array(
        'name'          => _x( 'Pressemitteilungen', 'taxonomy general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Pressemitteilung', 'taxonomy singular name'),
        'menu_name'     => __( 'Pressemitteilungen')
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'press_release' )
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'press_release', array( 'post' ), $args );    
}

add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', function ( $title ) {
    if( is_tax() ) {
        $tax = get_taxonomy( get_queried_object()->taxonomy );
        $title = sprintf( __( '%1$s: %2$s' ), 
                 $tax->labels->name, 
                 single_term_title( '', false ) );
    }
    return $title;
});
```

archive.php

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <h1 class="page-title"><?php echo get_the_archive_title( ); ?></h1>
    [...]
```

I've set up a test term `testterm1` in the `press_release` taxonomy in the WP admin, the resulting HTML in the archive page for mysite.com/press_release/testterm1/

```
<h1 class="page-title">Pressemitteilungen: test term1</h1>
```

Comment: I think I am not fully understanding how that works.. I exchanged my code in functions.php with your code. The two categories are created with singular word-forms: The name fields are 'Kommentar' and 'Pressemitteilung' and the corresponding title fields are 'kommentar' and 'pressemitteilung', meaning comment and press release. The plural forms I want to display on their indexes are called "Kommentare" and "Pressemitteilungen". So once it's an additional 'e' and once an additional 'en'.

Comment: @ThomasMaier What this does is that the archive should now use the value you set for "name" in your `$labels` array instead of "singular_name". I've updated the answer to show an example of what its doing. If you have set your `$labels` as direct translations of the English labels from your example, then you should be getting "Kommentare" on the archive page.

Comment: I have now my original post's code with the German expressions in functions.php, as well as the add_filter(... code from your answer underneath. Maybe it's not working because I use the wrong way of calling for it on archive.php? I use  <h2><?php echo single_term_title(); ?></h2>

Comment: @ThomasMaier Well, by using `single_term_title()` you're actually explicitly telling it to use the singular term! Can you include the archive title like this `<h2><?php echo get_the_archive_title(); ?></h2>;`

Comment: I thought so too, but it seems like it produces some kind of fallback version. The outcome is "Kategorie: Pressemitteilung". Instead of "Pressemitteilungen". I haven't specified anywhere a version that would result in the version with the colon. EDIT: Oh, right, it must be from the functions.php code that you gave me. The '%1$s: ' part can be gone, while '%2$s' should produce the Plural version on archive indexes (and the Singular version on single-post-displays.

Comment: this is wrong? I added the `$` to `labels` also. `add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', function ( $title ) {

    if( is_tax() ) {
        $tax = get_taxonomy( get_queried_object()->taxonomy );
        $title = sprintf( __( '%2$s' ),
                 $tax->$labels->name,
                 single_term_title( '', false ) );
    }
    return $title;
});`

Comment: @ThomasMaier Add the `$` in front label in  `$tax->$labels->name` won't work - "label" is a variable in the "$tax" object so you must access it like `$tax->$labels`. The problem I'm having is that I'm trying to guess what the rest of your code is... and obviously not guessing correctly :) Can you edit your question to include the names you are using for you single and archive theme pages and the code you are using to include the title in them?

Comment: I have updated the above code to match exactly the current state of the concerning code. Does this provide enough info? Generally said again: Display the plural version of a word, their category, on archives and its singular version on single posts.

Comment: @ThomasMaier I've edited my question to include all the code I added to get this to work on my test site. Take a look and let me know what is different in your own code, so we can try to see whats going wrong.

Comment: I am using your code in functions.php and have get_the_archive_title on archive.php, but is echoes 'Kategorie: Pressemitteilung' instead of 'Pressemitteilungen'. (without the 'Kategorie: ' but plural)...

Comment: @ThomasMaier I've no idea where it could be getting `Kategorie` from, because you are using a custom taxonomy, like in my code, are you not? Because the code you included for setting the labels is for setting up a taxonomy. If you're not doing that, then where are you setting the labels?

Comment: Me neither, I also discovered that when I change all terms to be plural, it still displays the singular version.... Does Wordpress somehow cache categories? Do I have to scrape all categories from the WordPress backend  because the functions-code creates everything on its own? (but then all connected posts return to category 'general').

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157192/discussion-between-thomas-maier-and-fluffykitten).